# Recovering a RAID5 array

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a raid5 array with 4 USB hard drives. One of the drives disappeared while the system was running, so I rebooted the computer but the drive didn't reappear. Then I checked the drives physically and one of them wasn't powered on, so I plugged it into an another USB port and it started working again. However I was unable to reassemble the array. `mdadm --examine --scan` returned the following `ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=2944b5db:2449ef62:6c849f70:becb3327 name=szerver:0`, but when I tried `mdadm --assemble /dev/md/0`, it returned with the following:

```
mdadm: cannot re-read metadata from /dev/dm-0 - aborting
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted
```

How can I recover the array or if that's not possible, the data from it?

Edit:

```
mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
       Version : 1.2
    Raid Level : raid0
 Total Devices : 4
   Persistence : Superblock is persistent

         State : inactive
Working Devices : 4

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

   -     253        3        -        /dev/dm-3
   -     253        1        -        /dev/dm-1
   -     253        2        -        /dev/dm-2
   -     253        0        -        /dev/dm-0
```

Which is strange because back then I created a RAID5 array, not a RAID0 array.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
md0 : inactive dm-3[0](S) dm-2[1](S) dm-1[4](S) dm-0[2](S)
      3906483976 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

Edit 2:
I found [this](http://www.fibrevillage.com/storage/676-how-to-fix-linux-mdadm-inactive-array) and started to use `mdadm --examine` on the drives and uploaded the results to [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2GFpT6kpsn/).

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1212306/edit) your question and add the output of both `cat /proc/mdstat` and `sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0` .  Thank you!

Comment: That is strange because those aren't even physical devices.  Those are showing Device Mapper names.  See:  https://superuser.com/questions/131519/what-is-this-dm-0-device/131520  Maybe also add the output from `sudo lsblk` to your question.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my last comment.  I would suggest building a new array with the physical drives since they are part of it.  You should be able to run `sudo mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sd[f-i]1`  Then run `watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat` to watch the rebuild.  See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8861/how-to-recover-a-crashed-linux-md-raid5-array

Comment: I read the linked answer and decided to do a S.M.A.R.T. self-test and noticed [this](https://pic8.co/sh/fQCfEk.png).

Comment: OK, this is very strange because I work with RAIDs at my job all the time, and I have not seen any of the arrays configured using Device Mappers that are tied to LVMs.  How did you create the array originally?  I only see 3 physical drives and 4 dev mappers listed.  It appears to still be missing one of the drives.

Comment: The laptop I try to recover the array on, only has 4 USB ports and I needed one of them, so I temporarily disconnected the 4th drive. I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial. [Here](https://pic8.co/sh/mhMpIt.png)'s the picture with all four disks connected.

Comment: According to the link you have given you should not see any dm devices but only the physical devices like sdf1 through sdi1.  I have no idea how you got the device mappers running as they shouldn't be there.  So, I am at a complete loss and would not be any more help beyond here.  Sorry about that!

Comment: I have no idea either. Since this is a home setup, I don't really care about understanding or utilizing deeper, more complicated parts of the system since I don't have to. And I don't know if the device mappers were active on the original system or they only appeared on this system. Anyway, all three disks I could run the self-test on, checked out as 'OK'.

Comment: I tried to re-create the array with the missing option but with no luck. The contents are unreadable, so I think that's about it. I have to re-download everything (~2 TB).

Comment: `dmsetup table` to maybe get an idea what those dm devices are. `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`, `mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /dev/sd[fgh]1` (leaving out sdi1, which failed first, to be re-added later) might have saved it, but if you already re-created, too late for that.